# Creating & Inserting into a SQL Table which contains data using a hyphen '-' in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm currently trying to figure out the best way to create a table that contains data (account number) utilizing a '-'. Here are my goals:

1. Be able to create the table and insert the account numbers into the AcctNum column, and keep the Prefix & Suffix rows empty ***because...***
2. I'm attempting to write a command that will automatically populate the prefix and suffix columns based off of what is populated BEFORE & AFTER the "-" *within the AcctNum column*.

Table example goal:

[image]

My code:

```
set echo on

/* ---------------
   Create table structure
   --------------- */

drop table accounts;

-----
-----

CREATE TABLE accounts (
    acctnum VARCHAR(10),
    prefix VARCHAR(5),
    suffix VARCHAR(5),
    PRIMARY KEY (acctnum),
);


INSERT ALL
    INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) values(123-0097,NULL,NULL)
    INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) values(X089-056,NULL,NULL)
    INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) values(123-0097,NULL,NULL)
    INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) values(123-0098,NULL,NULL)
    INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) values(F3377-D,NULL,NULL)
    INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) values(X089-057,NULL,NULL)
    INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) values(X089-058,NULL,NULL)
    INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) values(3-009712,NULL,NULL)

SELECT *
    FROM dual;


commit;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.   Thank you!

Comment: If your question is only about Oracle, please remote the extraneous tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a very strange way to insert multiple rows.  How about this?

```
INSERT INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) 
    SELECT '123-0097', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'X089-056', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '123-0097', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '123-0098', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'F3377-D', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'X089-057', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'X089-058', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '3-009712', NULL, NULL FROM DUAL ;
```

Note that the real improvement is putting single quotes around the string literals.

In addition, Oracle recommends using `VARCHAR2()` for character strings rather than `VARCHAR()`.

Comment: You'd need to have a `from dual` in every `select` for this to work in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood you, let's go!

1.Your insert command needs to be fixed, below is an example:

```
INSERT ALL
    INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) values('123-0097',NULL,NULL)
    INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) values('X089-056',NULL,NULL)
    INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) values('123-0098',NULL,NULL)
    INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) values('F3377-D',NULL,NULL)
    INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) values('X089-057',NULL,NULL)
    INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) values('X089-058',NULL,NULL)
    INTO accounts(acctnum, prefix, suffix) values('3-009712',NULL,NULL)
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

2.So, you need to create your command to get the other columns, example:

```
SELECT  
    NVL(SUBSTR(acctnum, 0, INSTR(acctnum, '-')-1), NULL) AS prefix,
    NVL(SUBSTR(acctnum, INSTR(acctnum, '-')+1, LENGTH(acctnum)), NULL) AS suffix
FROM accounts;
```

I used Oracle for example, for other Databases you'll need change the string functions.